# How to merge multiple columns with same content in the excel output file using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge

i have a pandas dataframe like below table. for each SITEID in the first column, i've same value for other columns like Priority, Region and Vendor but not same in the History column.

```
SITEID  Priority    Region  Vendor                          HISTORY
======  =========   ======  ======= =================================================================
E1149       P3        R10     NSN       09-09 : ZRBSCN8, LUE1149 : Connector Faulty : 00: 31
=====================================================================================================
E1149       P3        R10     NSN       09-08 : ZRBSCN8, LUE1149 (Fluctuation)BSS Cabling Fault: 00: 16
=====================================================================================================
E1149       P3        R10     NSN       09-07 : ZRBSCN8, LUE1149 : BSS Cabling Fault : 01: 02
=====================================================================================================
E1150       P3        R10     E//       09-09 : BABSCE3, LUE1150 & LUT7695 : Unclear : 01: 13
=====================================================================================================
E1150       P3        R10     E//       09-08 : BABSCE3, E1150 & T7695 : Unclear : 00: 18
=====================================================================================================
```

at first i want to merge the first four columns (SITEID, Priority, Region and Vendor) per each siteID and then put all the relevant records in the History column against it like below:

```
SITEID  Priority    Region  Vendor                          HISTORY
======  =========   ======  ======= =================================================================
E1149       P3        R10     NSN       09-09 : ZRBSCN8, LUE1149 : Connector Faulty : 00: 31
                                        09-08 : ZRBSCN8, LUE1149 (Fluctuation)BSS Cabling Fault:00: 16
                                        09-07 : ZRBSCN8, LUE1149 : BSS Cabling Fault : 01: 02
=====================================================================================================
E1150       P3        R10     E//       09-09 : BABSCE3, LUE1150 & LUT7695 : Unclear : 01: 13
                                        09-08 : BABSCE3, E1150 & T7695 : Unclear : 00: 18
=====================================================================================================
```

what is the most efficient way to do this in the excel output file using xlswriter etc? i tried many solutions like `swaplevel` but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simple `groupby` and `agg` using `.join` with delimiter `\n`:

```
cols = ['SITEID', 'Priority', 'Region', 'Vendor']
df_merged = df.groupby(cols, as_index=False).agg('\n'.join)
```

Then save this merged dataframe to excel as:

```
df_merged.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great idea and solution @Shubham Sharma this is exactly what i needed to have in the excel output file. thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply look for duplicate rows for the relevant columns with `.loc`. There are two parts to loc: 1. Rows and 2. columns:

1. For `rows`, you can use `.duplicated()` and specify the columns to look for duplicates by passing `subset=([])`. This will return `True` for duplicate rows.
2. For `columns`, you can use just pass the columns for the values that you want to change to blanks with `,['SITEID','Priority','Region','Vendor']]`
3. Finally, set these specified `rows` and `columns` to blank with `== ''`

---

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=(['SITEID','Priority','Region','Vendor'])),['SITEID','Priority','Region','Vendor']] = ''
df
Out[1]: 
  SITEID Priority Region Vendor  \
0  E1149       P3    R10    NSN   
1                                 
2                                 
3  E1150       P3    R10    E//   
4                                 

                                             HISTORY  
0  09-09 : ZRBSCN8, LUE1149 : Connector Faulty : ...  
1  09-08 : ZRBSCN8, LUE1149 (Fluctuation)BSS Cabl...  
2  09-07 : ZRBSCN8, LUE1149 : BSS Cabling Fault :...  
3  09-09 : BABSCE3, LUE1150 & LUT7695 : Unclear :...  
4  09-08 : BABSCE3, E1150 & T7695 : Unclear : 00: 18

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks David, great idea! the only issue is when i want to draw a border in the excel output file using xlswriter format, the line will be draw between the History column rows correctly as they're still in the different rows logically. any idea to can fix this excel formatting?

Comment: @Mahmood can you paste a picture of excel of your desired format?

Comment: @ David Erickson thank you. the desired format is exactly what Shubham Sharma posted above.